# Integral cohomology class associated to trefoil knots

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, knot-theory

> Is there any notion of an integral $\mathbb{Z}$ cohomology class associated to
>   trefoil knots?
>
> If one considers the trefoil knot in 3 dim, is there any associated
>   integral cohomology class for it?

My understanding and own attempts:

- I know that the trefoil knot and anti-trefoil knot have a different chirality. So this looks that there could be at least a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ cohomology class. Can it be associated with some $\mathbb{Z}$ cohomology class.

What I also found a technical Ref:
[0105190-An almost-integral universal Vassiliev invariant of knots](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0105190.pdf). Maybe experts know more.

Comment: what does this mean? an integral cohomology class of what? (and why trefoils...?)

Comment: What would you mean by a cohomology class associated to trefoil knots? It might be my ignorance of knot theory here, but I'm not even sure what sort of cohomology theory you might be asking about (based on a quick google search turning up alternative homology theories for knots like Khovanov homology). Given that you've tagged it with algebraic topology, I assume you want some topological space's cohomology. Are you thinking of something like the singular cohomology of $\Bbb{R}^3-K$, where $K$ is the knot?

Comment: yes - thanks for the comment

Comment: I think bordism group $\Omega^{3,Spin}(B \mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_8$, the odd classes in the $\mathbb{Z}_8$ can be detected by the trefoil knot. In the sense, the associated TQFT of the odd generator $\Omega^{3,Spin}(B \mathbb{Z}_2)$ has it path integral $Z=-1$ with the trefoil knot configuration.

Comment: But I wanted to have the integral $\mathbb{Z}$ class, instead of the $\mathbb{Z}_n$ torsion ones.

Comment: In this sense, I may say the Arf invariant is associated to the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ class and the trefoil knot. But I wonder whether there is another X invariant is associated to the $\mathbb{Z}$ class and the trefoil knot.